# Loading images using web service and Picasso, how to add inSampling size?

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I am using Picasso library to load and display images in a ViewPager. The images being loaded have high resolution, I would like to add an insampling size to them. I do not know, however, how or where I should add this insampling size attribute. My ViewPagerAdapter.java class has the following.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
   ImageView iv_page_image;
   inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,false);
   iv_page_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_page_image);
   String path = pageList.get(position).getPageImage();
   path = path.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
   if (path != null && !(path.equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
      Picasso.with(mContext).load(path)
         .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_empty)
         .into(iv_page_image, new Callback() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess() {

         }
         @Override
         public void onError() {
         }
      });
    }
((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
return itemView;
}
```

I would like to add something like the following to the images

```
private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with insampling?

Comment: I have modified my question. Because I am not receiving a bitmap, I am just curious how I can control the size? Making the imageView container smaller only makes the image look shrunk. I have added fitXY to my imageView in xml as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `.fit()` to your call to Picasso and it will automatically calculate the appropriate `inSampleSize` to use when decoding the image.

You will also probably want to use either `.centerInside()` or `.centerCrop()` to ensure the aspect ratio of the image is not altered when automatically resized.

Comment: fit() works only with ImageView, but what if i have LinearLayout implements Target?