# How Picasso downloading images

Tags: android, picasso

I have a question about mechanisms used by `Picasso` for downloading and caching images.

How does `Picasso` download an image? I know that it is using in sample size. Am I right? If image on a server is 1000x1000 but `ImageView` is only 400x400 then it will be download only 500x500 image and it will be cached. Or maybe it will be downloaded in full resolution and then scaled to a specific size.

Comment: you are wrong, it downloads full size images. There is no way to download  particular pixels of image.

Comment: so decodeStream from BitmapFactory and inSampleSize can not be used in InputStream from server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can browse source-code of Picasso at: https://github.com/square/picasso.

**Downloading images**

You can see that Picasso downloads images with implementation of `Downloader` interface. It uses default downloader named `OkHttpDownloader`, which utilizes OkHttp library. When it can't be loaded, Picasso uses `UrlConnectionDownloader`.

**Recognizing size of the images**

Picasso doesn't know size of the images before download. If you are developing back-end server, you can specify size of the images in some way, so your mobile application will know it by performing a concrete request, but it can't be recognized by Picasso itself. Picasso has to download image in a full size and then this image can be cropped or resized by this library.

**Cache**

We can find the following information about Cache in the Picasso documentation placed in source code:

> Picasso instance is automatically initialized with defaults that are
>   suitable to most implementations.
>
> - LRU memory cache of 15% the available application RAM
> - Disk cache of 2% storage space up to 50MB but no less than 5MB. (Note: this is only available on API 14+ *or* if you are using
>     a standalone library that provides a disk cache on all API levels like
>     OkHttp)
> - Three download threads for disk and network access.

It explains usage of cache in this library quite clearly.
I'm just not sure, if Picasso stores images before transformation (resizing, cropping, etc.) or after transformation in cache. First option seems more reasonable for me, because we decide to apply a different transformation later, so we may want to keep original image.

Comment: thax for explanation but i dont really sure why there can not be used decodeStream from BitmapFactory and inSampleSize ? It will not work in this situation?

Comment: I suppose there are many implementations and possible ways to solve this problem and maybe it can be done differently. I haven't checked all the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Here is actual code I am - and I'm sure many more people are - using

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Picasso has no way of knowing it should download only 500*500 pixels. The `fit()` and `centercrop()` methods will make it fit even when picture is bigger than needed.

Comment: Fit() will be fired after view will be created so Picasso will know view measures.

Comment: Yes it uses measures of imageview, but Picasso doesn't know your server and if it supports creating dynamically sized images to request one with specific size. If you want specific size of image you need to implement it on the server and call it with different url. for example call www.example.com/image-1000-1000.jpg for 1000*1000 image and www.example.com/image-500-500.jpg for 500*500 image - but that has to be implemented on the server.

Comment: why not use BitmapFactory and inSampleSize? u can use decodeStream http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518116/loading-images-using-web-service-and-picasso-how-to-add-insampling-size

Comment: The accepted answer is literally telling you to use fit() and centerCrop() like i did in my answer. I don't understand what more do you need.

Comment: I wanted to understand how 'Picasso' download image - what are the resolutions of downloaded images and whether 'ImageView' resolutions affect downloaded images. Now i know Images will be downloaded from server in full resolution. But 'Bitmap' that will be used in 'ImageView' will be scaled if You use 'fit()' method because then 'Picasso' will know resolution of 'ImageView' and will use InSampleSize to read this from cache.

Comment: This knowledge is important when You will download large images. Your answer would be good if I wanted a code which will work in most cases but not with large images - because than You must be aware of the mechanism so as not to see 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError'

Comment: "Picasso has no way of knowing it should download only 500*500 pixels. The fit() and centercrop() methods will make it fit even when picture is bigger than needed." It's right up there. I told you multiple times that picasso will always download full image from url provided.

Comment: but from cache there will be used inSampleSizwe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85151/discussion-between-krzysztof-itaudit-and-poss).